# Does Firefox OS App Manager support SD card emulation?

Tags: sd-card, firefox-os

I would like to write an app for Firefox OS which uses the SD card through the Device Storage API. Does the App Manager emulate the SD card somehow?

If yes, how can I enable it? I haven't seen any SD card related menu item in the App Manager.

Comment: Why is the downvote? How can I improve the question?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use [the Device Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Storage_API) in your app rather than the SD card directly? I'd assume the App Manager does emulate the Device Storage API? In fact there's an "sdcard" device storage area.

Comment: Hello! It could be that people are having a hard time with this question because it is poorly formed. Check out the  [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help section. Good luck!

Comment: The App Manager does not do anything. The *simulator* emulates the SD card. The *phone* reads from physical SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available through the Device Storage API in the emulator.

Stored files can be found under the following directory:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/extensions/fxos_1_3_simulator@mozilla.org/profile/fake-sdcard
```